# Glass mapper A/B testing error - Model item passed as rendering instead of model

Tags: glass-mapper

I am using Sitecore 9.3 with Glass.Mapper 5.6.163.

When I setup simple A/B testing with different content datasource. I get the below error.

Inner Exception: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type "Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel", but the dictionary requires a model item of type `<Model>`

I also noticed that in "Test the Component" window, the "Test Content Item" field starts showing the rendering instead of the actual content item it was assigned earlier.

[image]

I am not quite sure why but tt seems to me that it is related to Glass Mapper.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to see if this issue isn't fixed in later versions of glass mapper, I can see two PRs created regarding A/B testing errors. If you take a look here https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/pulls?q=is%3Apr+is%3Aclosed the first pull request https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/pull/423 seems to be related to glass mapper not returning the proper datasource items for A/B tests.